# Lowercase first letter of a parameter in the "dotnet new" template engine

Tags: dotnet-cli, dotnet-new

I am building a template using the `dotnet new` template engine.

I have a parameter that looks like this:

```
"symbols": {
  "rootEntity": {
    "displayName": "Root Entity",
    "type": "parameter",
    "datatype": "string",
    "replaces": "Notebook",
    "defultName": "Notebook",
    "isRequired": false,
    "description": "An example root level data entity"
   },
   ... other parameters here
}
```

It seems to mostly work, but it only replaces `Notebook`, not `notebook`.  I could add another parameter for the lowercase version, but that requires users to type it in twice (yuck).

I saw the `casing` [generator](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-Symbols-Generators), but it does all uppercase or all lowercase (not just the first letter).

Digging more, I found a thing called a `form` that has the options `firstLowerCase` and `firstUpperCase`.  But I can't find any examples using `forms`, only `symbols` (as shown in my example).

So, I have two possible questions (either will work):

- How can I lowercase or uppercase the first letter of a symbol variable
- How can I use `forms` in a template.

(I would prefer the second question as that enables me to use all the forms, but the first will get me moving forward, so I would be happy with either.)

Answer (score 0):

### About forms

To use a form, it must be declared in the `forms` section, on the same level as the `symbols` section. After that, the form can be used where it is expected, for example, in the `derived` parameters. In the example below, there is a parameter `UserName`, and a transformative `derived` parameter that transforms the value of `UserName` to lowercase:

```
{
    "author": "Author",
    "name": "My template",
    "identity": "My.Template.Boo",
    "shortName": "mt",
    "symbols": {
        "UserName": {
            "displayName": "User name",
            "type": "parameter",
            "datatype": "string",
            "replaces": "UserName"
        },
        "UserNameLowerCase": {
            "type": "derived",
            "valueSource": "UserName",
            "valueTransform": "lowerCaseForm",
            "replaces": "username"
        }
    },
    "forms": {
        "lowerCaseForm": {
            "identifier": "lowerCase"
        }
    }
}
```

### Lowercase first letter of a parameter

So, you have such a template.json file:

```
{
    "author": "Author",
    "name": "My template",
    "identity": "My.Template.Boo",
    "shortName": "mt",
    "symbols": {
        "rootEntity": { // parameter from command line
            "displayName": "Root Entity",
            "type": "parameter",
            "datatype": "string",
            "replaces": "Notebook",
            "defultName": "Notebook",
            "isRequired": false,
            "description": "An example root level data entity"
        }
    }
}
```

And you want to have a source file with the following code:

```
Upper: Notebook
lower: notebook
```

And after executing the command `dotnet new mt --RootEntity "Hello world"` you need a file with the following contents (as far as I understand):

```
Upper: Hello world
lower: Hello world
```

I suggest you use the `derived` parameter and an empty form:

```
{
    "author": "Author",
    "name": "My template",
    "identity": "My.Template.Boo",
    "shortName": "mt",
    "symbols": {
        "rootEntity": {
            "displayName": "Root Entity",
            "type": "parameter",
            "datatype": "string",
            "replaces": "Notebook",
            "defultName": "Notebook",
            "isRequired": false,
            "description": "An example root level data entity"
        },
        "rootEntityLowerCase": {
            "type": "derived",
            "valueSource": "rootEntity",
            "valueTransform": "notTransform",
            "replaces": "notebook"
        }
    },
    "forms": {
        "notTransform":{    
        }
    }
}
```

In the `forms` section, the `notTransform` form is declared. This form does nothing - it is empty. `rootEntityLowerCase` is a `derived` parameter that takes the value of the `rootEntity` parameter and applies to it the transformation specified by the `notTransform` form (this form does nothing :)). The value of the `rootEntityLowerCase` parameter is inserted wherever the `notebook` text occurs.